# How to remove delay before Lottie animation starts playing

Tags: lottie

I have this Lottie animation:

https://lottiefiles.com/share/hmpf0dsc#_=_

But there is a delay before it starts. The delay feels around 800 - 1 second. How can I remove this in the JSON?

Here is the start of the JSON (not complete because too large for SO):

```
{"v":"4.11.1","fr":60,"ip":0,"op":116,"w":36,"h":46,"nm":"TwitterHeart","ddd":0,"assets":[],"layers":[{"ddd":0,"ind":1,"ty":4,"nm":"Dot14","sr":1,"ks":{"o":{"a":0,"k":100,"ix":11},"r":{"a":0,"k":-320,"ix":10},"p":{"a":0,"k":[25,25,0],"ix":2},"a":{"a":0,"k":[0,0,0],"ix":1},"s":{"a":0,"k":[40,40,100],"ix":6}},"ao":0,"shapes":[{"ty":"gr","it":[{"ind":0,"ty":"sh","ix":1,"ks":{"a":0,"k":{"i":[[0,0],[0,0]],"o":[[0,0],[0,0]],"v":[[-37.5,-40.5],[-1,0.5]],"c":false},"ix":2},"nm":"Path 1","mn":"ADBE Vector Shape - Group","hd":false},{"ty":"tm","s":{"a":1,"k":[{"i":{"x":[0.833],"y":[0.833]},"o":{"x":[0.167],"y":[0.167]},"n":["0p833_0p833_0p167_0p167"],"t":44,"s":[47],"e":[29]},{"i":{"x":[0.833],"y":[0.833]},"o":{"x":[0.167],"y":[0.167]},"n":["0p833_0p833_0p167_0p167"],"t":56,"s":[29],"e":[9]},{"t":78}],"ix":1},"e":{"a":1,"k":[{"i":{"x":[0.833],"y":[0.833]},"o":{"x":[0.167],"y":[0.167]},"n":["0p833_0p833_0p167_0p167"],"t":44,"s":[48],"e":[30]},{"i":{"x":[0.833],"y":[0.833]},"o":{"x":[0.167],"y":[0.167]},"n":["0p833_0p833_0p167_0p167"],"t":56,"s":[30],"e":[10]},{"t":78}],"ix":2},"o":{"a":0,"k":0,"ix":3},"m":1,"ix":2,"nm":"Trim Paths 1","mn":"ADBE Vector Filter - Trim","hd":false},{"ty":"st","c":{"a":1,"k":[{"i":{"x":[0.833],"y":[0.833]},"o":{"x":[0.167],"y":[0.167]},"n":["0p833_0p833_0p167_0p167"],"t":44,"s":[0.631372570992,0.811764717102,0.937254905701,1],"e":[0.819607853889,0.647058844566,0.909803926945,1]},{"t":56}],"ix":3},"o":{"a":0,"k":100,"ix":4},"w":{"a":1,"k":[{"i":{"x":[0.833],"y":[0.833]},"o":{"x":[0.167],"y":[0.167]},"n":["0p833_0p833_0p167_0p167"],"t":44,"s":[5],"e":[2]},{"i":{"x":[0.833],"y":[0.833]},"o":{"x":[0.167],"y":[0.167]},"n":["0p833_0p833_0p167_0p167"],"t":56,"s":[2],"e":[0]},{"t":70}],"ix":5},"lc":2,"lj":1,"ml":4,"nm":"Stroke 1","mn":"ADBE Vector Graphic - Stroke","hd":false},{"ty":"tr","p":{"a":0,"k":[0,0],"ix":2},"a":{"a":0,"k":[0,0],"ix":1},"s":{"a":0,"k":[100,100],"ix":3},"r":{"a":0,"k":0,"ix":6},"o":{"a":0,"k":100,"ix":7},"sk":{"a":0,"k":0,"ix":4},"sa":{"a":0,"k":0,"ix":5},"nm":"Transform"}],"nm":"Shape 1","np":3,"cix":2,"ix":1,"mn":"ADBE Vector Group","hd":false}],"ip":44,"op":90,"st":-44,"bm":0},{"ddd":0,"ind":2,"ty":4,"nm":"Dot13","sr":1,"ks":{"o":{"a":0,"k":100,"ix":11},"r":{"a":0,"k":-306.6,"ix":10},"p":{"a":0,"k":[25,25,0],"ix":2},"a":{"a":0,"k":[0,0,0],"ix":1},"s":{"a":0,"k":[40,40,100],"ix":6}},"ao":0,"shapes":[{"ty":"gr","it":[{"ind":0,"ty":"sh","ix":1,"ks":{"a":0,"k":{"i":[[0,0],[0,0]],"o":[[0,0],[0,0]],"v":[[-37.5,-40.5],[-1,0.5]],"c":false},"ix":2},"nm":"Path 1","mn":"ADBE Vector Shape - Group","hd":false},{"ty":"tm","s":{"a":1,"k":[{"i":{"x":[0.833],"y":[0.833]},"o":{"x":[0.167],"y":[0.167]},"n":["0p833_0p833_0p167_0p167"],"t":44,"s":[44],"e":[19]},{"i":{"x":[0.833],"y":[0.833]},"o":{"x":[0.167],"y":[0.167]},"n":["0p833_0p833_0p167_0p167"],"t":56,"s":[19],"e":[0]},{"t":89}],"ix":1},"e":{"a":1,"k":[{"i":{"x":[0.833],"y":[0.833]},"o":{"x":[0.167],"y":[0.167]},"n":["0p833_0p833_0p167_0p167"],"t":44,"s":[45],"e":[20]},{"i":{"x":[0.833],"y":[0.833]},"o":{"x":[0.167],"y":[0.167]},"n":["0p833_0p833_0p167_0p167"],"t":56,"s":[20],"e":[1]},{"t":89}],"ix":2},"o":{"a":0,"k":0,"ix":3},"m":1,"ix":2,"nm":"Trim Paths 1","mn":"ADBE Vector Filter - Trim","hd":false},{"ty":"st","c":{"a":1,"k":[{"i":{"x":[0.833],"y":[0.833]},"o":{"x":[0.167],"y":[0.167]},"n":["0p833_0p833_0p167_0p167"],"t":44,"s":[0.658823549747,0.800000011921,0.96862745285,1],"e":[0.815686285496,0.654901981354,0.905882358551,1]},{"t":56}],"ix":3},"o":{"a":0,"k":100,"ix":4},"w":{"a":1,"k":[{"i":{"x":[0.833],"y":[0.833]},"o":{"x":[0.167],"y":[0.167]},"n":["0p833_0p833_0p167_0p167"],"t":56,"s":[5],"e":[0]},{"t":89}],"ix":5},"lc":2,"lj":1,"ml":4,"nm":"Stroke 1","mn":"ADBE Vector Graphic - Stroke","hd":false},{"ty":"tr","p":{"a":0,"k":[0,0],"ix":2},"a":{"a":0,"k":[0,0],"ix":1},"s":{"a":0,"k":[100,100],"ix":3},"r":{"a":0,"k":0,"ix":6},"o":{"a":0,"k":100,"ix":7},"sk":{"a":0,"k":0,"ix":4},"sa":{"a":0,"k":0,"ix":5},"nm":"Transform"}],"nm":"Shape 1","np":3,"cix":2,"ix":1,"mn":"ADBE Vector Group","hd":false}],"ip":44,"op":90,"st":-44,"bm":0},{"ddd":0,"ind":3,"ty":4,"nm":"Dot12","sr":1,"ks":{"o":{"a":0,"k":100,"ix":11},"r":{"a":0,"k":-271.7,"ix":10},"p":{"a":0,"k":[25,25,0],"ix":2},"a":{"a":0,"k":[0,0,0],"ix":1},"s":{"a":0,"k":[40,40,100],"ix":6}},"ao":0,"shapes":[{"ty":"gr","it":[{"ind":0,"ty":"sh","ix":1,"ks":{"a":0,"k":{"i":[[0,0],[0,0]],"o":[[0,0],[0,0]],"v":[[-37.5,-40.5],[-1,0.5]],"c":false},"ix":2},"nm":"Path 1","mn":"ADBE Vector Shape - Group","hd":false},{"ty":"tm","s":{"a":1,"k":[{"i":{"x":[0.833],"y":[0.833]},"o":{"x":[0.167],"y":[0.167]},"n":["0p833_0p833_0p167_0p167"],"t":44,"s":[47],"e":[29]},{"i":{"x":[0.833],"y":[0.833]},"o":{"x":[0.167],"y":[0.167]},"n":["0p833_0p833_0p167_0p167"],"t":56,"s":[29],"e":[9]},{"t":78}],"ix":1},"e":{"a":1,"k":[{"i":{"x":[0.833],"y":[0.833]},"o":{"x":[0.167],"y":[0.167]},"n":["0p833_0p833_0p167_0p167"],"t":44,"s":[48],"e":[30]},{"i":{"x":[0.833],"y":[0.833]},"o":{"x":[0.167],"y":[0.167]},"n":["0p833_0p833_0p167_0p167"],"t":56,"s":[30],"e":[10]},{"t":78}],"ix":2},"o":{"a":0,"k":0,"ix":3},"m":1,"ix":2,"nm":"Trim Paths 1","mn":"ADBE Vector Filter - Trim","hd":false},{"ty":"st","c":{"a":1,"k":[{"i":{"x":[0.833],"y":[0.833]},"o":{"x":[0.167],"y":[0.167]},"n":["0p833_0p833_0p167_0p167"],"t":44,"s":[0.784313738346,0.588235318661,0.901960790157,1],"e":[0.890196084976,0.819607853889,0.580392181873,1]},{"t":56}],"ix":3},"o":{"a":0,"k":100,"ix":4},"w":{"a":1,"k":[{"i":{"x":[0.833],"y":[0.833]},"o":{"x":[0.167],"y":[0.167]},"n":["0p833_0p833_0p167_0p167"],"t":44,"s":[5],"e":[2]},{"i":{"x":[0.833],"y":[0.833]},"o":{"x":[0.167],"y":[0.167]},"n":["0p833_0p833_0p167_0p167"],"t":56,"s":[2],"e":[0]},{"t":70}],"ix":5},"lc":2,"lj":1,"ml":4,"nm":"Stroke 1","mn":"ADBE Vector Graphic - Stroke","hd":false},{"ty":"tr","p":{"a":0,"k":[0,0],"ix":2},"a":{"a":0,"k":[0,0],"ix":1},"s":{"a":0,"k":[100,100],"ix":3},"r":{"a":0,"k":0,"ix":6},"o":{"a":0,"k":100,"ix":7},"sk":{"a":0,"k":0,"ix":4},"sa":{"a":0,"k":0,"ix":5},"nm":"Transform"}],"nm":"Shape 1","np":3,"cix":2,"ix":1,"mn":"ADBE Vector Group","hd":false}],"ip":44,"op":90,"st":-44,"bm":0},{"ddd":0,"ind":4,"ty":4,"nm":"Dot11","sr":1,"ks":{"o":{"a":0,"k":100,"ix":11},"r":{"a":0,"k":-258.3,"ix":10},"p":{"a":0,"k":[25,25,0],"ix":2},"a":{"a":0,"k":[0,0,0],"ix":1},"s":{"a":0,"k":[40,40,100],"ix":6}},"ao":0,"shapes":[{"ty":"gr","it":[{"ind":0,"ty":"sh","ix":1,"ks":{"a":0,"k":{"i":[[0,0],[0,0]],"o":[[0,0],[0,0]],"v":[[-37.5,-40.5],[-1,0.5]],"c":false},"ix":2},"nm":"Path 1","mn":"ADBE Vector Shape - Group","hd":false},{"ty":"tm","s":{"a":1,"k":[{"i":{"x":[0.833],"y":[0.833]},"o":{"x":[0.167],"y":[0.167]},"n":["0p833_0p833_0p167_0p167"],"t":44,"s":[44],"e":[19]},{"i":{"x":[0.833],"y":[0.833]},"o":{"x":[0.167],"y":[0.167]},"n":["0p833_0p833_0p167_0p167"],"t":56,"s":[19],"e":[0]},{"t":89}],"ix":1},"e":{"a":1,"k":[{"i":{"x":[0.833],"y":[0.833]},"o":{"x":[0.167],"y":[0.167]},"n":["0p833_0p833_0p167_0p167"],"t":44,"s":[45],"e":[20]},{"i":{"x":[0.833],"y":[0.833]},"o":{"x":[0.167],"y":[0.167]},"n":["0p833_0p833_0p167_0p167"],"t":56,"s":[20],"e":[1]},{"t":89}],"ix":2},"o":{"a":0,"k":0,"ix":3},"m":1,"ix":2,"nm":"Trim Paths 1","mn":"ADBE Vector Filter - Trim","hd":false},{"ty":"st","c":{"a":1,"k":[{"i":{"x":[0.833],"y":[0.833]},"o":{"x":[0.167],"y":[0.167]},"n":["0p833_0p833_0p167_0p167"],"t":44,"s":[0.784313738346,0.61960786581,0.89411765337,1],"e":[0.921568632126,0.749019622803,0.32549020648,1]},{"i":{"x":[0.833],"y":[0.833]},"o":{"x":[0.167],"y":[0.167]},"n":["0p833_0p833_0p167_0p167"],"t":56,"s":[0.921568632126,0.749019622803,0.32549020648,1],"e":[0.549019634724,0.274509817362,0.709803938866,1]},{"t":66}],"ix":3},"o":{"a":0,"k":100,"ix":4},"w":{"a":1,"k":[{"i":{"x":[0.833],"y":[0.833]},"o":{"x":[0.167],"y":[0.167]},"n":["0p833_0p833_0p167_0p167"],"t":56,"s":[5],"e":[0]},{"t":89}],"ix":5},"lc":2,"lj":1,"ml":4,"nm":"Stroke 1","mn":"ADBE Vector Graphic - Stroke","hd":false},{"ty":"tr","p":{"a":0,"k":[0,0],"ix":2},"a":{"a":0,"k":[0,0],"ix":1},"s":{"a":0,"k":[100,100],"ix":3},"r":{"a":0,"k":0,"ix":6},"o":{"a":0,"k":100,"ix":7},"sk":{"a":0,"k":0,"ix":4},"sa":{"a":0,"k":0,"ix":5},"nm":"Transform"}],"nm":"Shape 1","np":3,"cix":2,"ix":1,"mn":"ADBE Vector Group","hd":false}],"ip":44,"op":90,"st":-44,"bm":0},{"ddd":0,"ind":5,"ty":4,"nm":"Dot10","sr":1,"ks":{"o":{"a":0,"k":100,"ix":11},"r":{"a":0,"k":-220.3,"ix":10},"p":{"a":0,"k":[25,25,0],"ix":2},"a":{"a":0,"k":[0,0,0],"ix":1},"s":{"a":0,"k":[40,40,100],"ix":6}},"ao":0,"shapes":[{"ty":"gr","it":[{"ind":0,"ty":"sh","ix":1,"ks":{"a":0,"k":{"i":[[0,0],[0,0]],"o":[[0,0],[0,0]],"v":[[-37.5,-40.5],[-1,0.5]],"c":false},"ix":2},"nm":"Path 1","mn":"ADBE Vector Shape - Group","hd":false},{"ty":"tm","s":{"a":1,"k":[{"i":{"x":[0.833],"y":[0.833]},"o":{"x":[0.167],"y":[0.167]},"n":["0p833_0p833_0p167_0p167"],"t":44,"s":[47],"e":[29]},{"i":{"x":[0.833],"y":[0.833]},"o":{"x":[0.167],"y":[0.167]},"n":["0p833_0p833_0p167_0p167"],"t":56,"s":[29],"e":[9]},{"t":78}],"ix":1},"e":{"a":1,"k":[{"i":{"x":[0.833],"y":[0.833]},"o":{"x":[0.167],"y":[0.167]},"n":["0p833_0p833_0p167_0p167"],"t":44,"s":[48],"e":[30]},{"i":{"x":[0.833],"y":[0.833]},"o":{"x":[0.167],"y":[0.167]},"n":["0p833_0p833_0p167_0p167"],"t":56,"s":[30],"e":[10]},{"t":78}],"ix":2},"o":{"a":0,"k":0,"ix":3},"m":1,"ix":2,"nm":"Trim Paths 1","mn":"ADBE Vector Filter - Trim","hd":false},{"ty":"st","c":{"a":1,"k":[{"i":{"x":[0.833],"y":[0.833]},"o":{"x":[0.167],"y":[0.167]},"n":["0p833_0p833_0p167_0p167"],"t":44,"s":[0.607843160629,0.886274516582,0.78823530674,1],"e":[0.792156875134,0.737254917622,0.600000023842,1]},{"t":56}],"ix":3},"o":{"a":0,"k":100,"ix":4},"w":{"a":1,"k":[{"i":{"x":[0.833],"y":[0.833]},"o":{"x":[0.167],"y":[0.167]},"n":["0p833_0p833_0p167_0p167"],"t":44,"s":[5],"e":[2]},{"i":{"x":[0.833],"y":[0.833]},"o":{"x":[0.167],"y":[0.167]},"n":["0p833_0p833_0p167_0p167"],"t":56,"s":[2],"e":[0]},{"t":70}],"ix":5},"lc":2,"lj":1,"ml":4,"nm":"Stroke 1","mn":"ADBE Vector Graphic - Stroke","hd":false},{"ty":"tr","p":{"a":0,"k":[0,0],"ix":2},"a":{"a":0,"k":[0,0],"ix":1},"s":{"a":0,"k":[100,100],"ix":3},"r":{"a":0,"k":0,"ix":6},"o":{"a":0,"k":100,"ix":7},"sk":{"a":0,"k":0,"ix":4},"sa":{"a":0,"k":0,"ix":5},"nm":"Transform"}],"nm":"Shape 1","np":3,"cix":2,"ix":1,"mn":"ADBE Vector Group","hd":false}],"ip":44,"op":90,"st":-44,"bm":0},{"ddd":0,"ind":6,"ty":4,"nm":"Dot9","sr":1,"ks":{"o":{"a":0,"k":100,"ix":11},"r":{"a":0,"k":-206.9,"ix":10},"p":{"a":0,"k":[25,25,0],"ix":2},"a":{"a":0,"k":[0,0,0],"ix":1},"s":{"a":0,"k":[40,40,100],"ix":6}},"ao":0,"shapes":[{"ty":"gr","it":[{"ind":0,"ty":"sh","ix":1,"ks":{"a":0,"k":{"i":[[0,0],[0,0]],"o":[[0,0],[0,0]],"v":[[-37.5,-40.5],[-1,0.5]],"c":false},"ix":2},"nm":"Path 1","mn":"ADBE Vector Shape - Group","hd":false},{"ty":"tm","s":{"a":1,"k":[{"i":{"x":[0.833],"y":[0.833]},"o":{"x":[0.167],"y":[0.167]},"n":["0p833_0p833_0p167_0p167"],"t":44,"s":[44],"e":[19]},{"i":{"x":[0.833],"y":[0.833]},"o":{"x":[0.167],"y":[0.167]},"n":["0p833_0p833_0p167_0p167"],"t":56,"s":[19],"e":[0]},{"t":89}],"ix":1},"e":{"a":1,"k":[{"i":{"x":[0.833],"y":[0.833]},"o":{"x":[0.167],"y":[0.167]},"n":["0p833_0p833_0p167_0p167"],"t":44,"s":[45],"e":[20]},{"i":{"x":[0.833],"y":[0.833]},"o":{"x":[0.167],"y":[0.167]},"n":["0p833_0p833_0p167_0p167"],"t":56,"s":[20],"e":[1]},{"t":89}],"ix":2},"o":{"a":0,"k":0,"ix":3},"m":1,"ix":2,"nm":"Trim Paths 1","mn":"ADBE Vector Filter - Trim","hd":false},{"ty":"st","c":{"a":1,"k":[{"i":{"x":[0.833],"y":[0.833]},"o":{"x":[0.167],"y":[0.167]},"n":["0p833_0p833_0p167_0p167"],"t":44,"s":[0.61960786581,0.882352948189,0.780392169952,1],"e":[0.792156875134,0.737254917622,0.600000023842,1]},{"i":{"x":[0.833],"y":[0.833]},"o":{"x":[0.167],"y":[0.167]},"n":["0p833_0p833_0p167_0p167"],"t":56,"s":[0.792156875134,0.737254917622,0.600000023842,1],"e":[0.549019634724,0.274509817362,0.709803938866,1]},{"t":66}],"ix":3},"o":{"a":0,"k":100,"ix":4},"w":{"a":1,"k":[{"i":{"x":[0.833],"y":[0.833]},"o":{"x":[0.167],"y":[0.167]},"n":["0p833_0p833_0p167_0p167"],"t":56,"s":[5],"e":[0]},{"t":89}],"ix":5},"lc":2,"lj":1,"ml":4,"nm":"Stroke 1","mn":"ADBE Vector Graphic - Stroke","hd":false},{"ty":"tm","s":{"a":0,"k":44,"ix":1},"e":{"a":0,"k":45,"ix":2},"o":{"a":0,"k":0,"ix":3},"m":1,"ix":4,"nm":"Trim Paths 2","mn":"ADBE Vector Filter - Trim","hd":false},{"ty":"tr","p":{"a":0,"k":[0,0],"ix":2},"a":{"a":0,"k":[0,0],"ix":1},"s":{"a":0,"k":[100,100],"ix":3},"r":{"a":0,"k":0,"ix":6},"o":{"a":0,"k":100,"ix":7},"sk":{"a":0,"k":0,"ix":4},"sa":{"a":0,"k":0,"ix":5},"nm":"Transform"}],"nm":"Shape 1","np":4,"cix":2,"ix":1,"mn":"ADBE Vector Group","hd":false}],"ip":44,"op":90,"st":-44,"bm":0},{"ddd":0,"ind":7,"ty":4,"nm":"Dot8","sr":1,"ks":{"o":{"a":0,"k":100,"ix":11},"r":{"a":0,"k":-168.2,"ix":10},"p":{"a":0,"k":[25,25,0],"ix":2},"a":{"a":0,"k":[0,0,0],"ix":1},"s":{"a":0,"k":[40,40,100],"ix":6}},"ao":0,"shapes":[{"ty":"gr","it":[{"ind":0,"ty":"sh","ix":1,"ks":{"a":0,"k":{"i":[[0,0],[0,0]],"o":[[0,0],[0,0]],"v":[[-37.5,-40.5],[-1,0.5]],"c":false},"ix":2},"nm":"Path 1","mn":"ADBE Vector Shape - Group","hd":false},{"ty":"tm","s":{"a":1,"k":[{"i":{"x":[0.833],"y":[0.833]},"o":{"x":[0.167],"y":[0.167]},"n":["0p833_0p833_0p167_0p167"],"t":44,"s":[47],"e":[29]},{"i":{"x":[0.833],"y":[0.833]},"o":{"x":[0.167],"y":[0.167]},"n":["0p833_0p833_0p167_0p167"],"t":56,"s":[29],"e":[9]},{"t":78}],"ix":1},"e":{"a":1,"k":[{"i":{"x":[0.833],"y":[0.833]},"o":{"x":[0.167],"y":[0.167]},"n":["0p833_0p833_0p167_0p167"],"t":44,"s":[48],"e":[30]},{"i":{"x":[0.833],"y":[0.833]},"o":{"x":[0.167],"y":[0.167]},"n":["0p833_0p833_0p167_0p167"],"t":56,"s":[30],"e":[10]},{"t":78}],"ix":2},"o":{"a":0,"k":0,"ix":3},"m":1,"ix":2,"nm":"Trim Paths 1","mn":"ADBE Vector Filter - Trim","hd":false},{"ty":"st","c":{"a":1,"k":[{"i":{"x":[0.833],"y":[0.833]},"o":{"x":[0.167],"y":[0.167]},"n":["0p833_0p833_0p167_0p167"],"t":44,"s":[0.858823537827,0.623529434204,0.68235296011,1],"e":[0.329411774874,0.596078455448,0.800000011921,1]},{"t":56}],"ix":3},"o":{"a":0,"k":100,"ix":4},"w":{"a":1,"k":[{"i":{"x":[0.833],"y":[0.833]},"o":{"x":[0.167],"y":[0.167]},"n":["0p833_0p833_0p167_0p167"],"t":44,"s":[5],"e":[2]},{"i":{"x":[0.833],"y":[0.833]},"o":{"x":[0.167],"y":[0.167]},"n":["0p833_0p833_0p167_0p167"],"t":56,"s":[2],"e":[0]},{"t":70}],"ix":5},"lc":2,"lj":1,"ml":4,"nm":"Stroke 1","mn":"ADBE Vector Graphic - Stroke","hd":false},{"ty":"tr","p":{"a":0,"k":[0,0],"ix":2},"a":{"a":0,"k":[0,0],"ix":1},"s":{"a":0,"k":[100,100],"ix":3},"r":{"a":0,"k":0,"ix":6},"o":{"a":0,"k":100,"ix":7},"sk":{"a":0,"k":0,"ix":4},"sa":{"a":0,"k":0,"ix":5},"nm":"Transform"}],"nm":"Shape 1","np":3,"cix":2,"ix":1,"mn":"ADBE Vector Group","hd":false}],"ip":44,"op":90,"st":-44,"bm":0},{"ddd":0,"ind":8,"ty":4,"nm":"Dot7","sr":1,"ks":{"o":{"a":0,"k":100,"ix":11},"r":{"a":0,"k":-154.8,"ix":10},"p":{"a":0,"k":[25,25,0],"ix":2},"a":{"a":0,"k":[0,0,0],"ix":1},"s":{"a":0,"k":[40,40,100],"ix":6}},"ao":0,"shapes":[{"ty":"gr","it":[{"ind":0,"ty":"sh","ix":1,"ks":{"a":0,"k":{"i":[[0,0],[0,0]],"o":[[0,0],[0,0]],"v":[[-37.5,-40.5],[-1,0.5]],"c":false},"ix":2},"nm":"Path 1","mn":"ADBE Vector Shape - Group","hd":false},{"ty":"tm","s":{"a":1,"k":[{"i":{"x":[0.833],"y":[0.833]},"o":{"x":[0.167],"y":[0.167]},"n":["0p833_0p833_0p167_0p167"],"t":44,"s":[44],"e":[19]},{"i":{"x":[0.833],"y":[0.833]},"o":{"x":[0.167],"y":[0.167]},"n":["0p833_0p833_0p167_0p167"],"t":56,"s":[19],"e":[0]},{"t":89}],"ix":1},"e":{"a":1,"k":[{"i":{"x":[0.833],"y":[0.833]},"o":{"x":[0.167],"y":[0.167]},"n":["0p833_0p833_0p167_0p167"],"t":44,"s":[45],"e":[20]},{"i":{"x":[0.833],"y":[0.833]},"o":{"x":[0.167],"y":[0.167]},"n":["0p833_0p833_0p167_0p167"],"t":56,"s":[20],"e":[1]},{"t":89}],"ix":2},"o":{"a":0,"k":0,"ix":3},"m":1,"ix":2,"nm":"Trim Paths 1","mn":"ADBE Vector Filter - Trim","hd":false},{"ty":"st","c":{"a":1,"k":[{"i":{"x":[0.833],"y":[0.833]},"o":{"x":[0.167],"y":[0.167]},"n":["0p833_0p833_0p167_0p167"],"t":44,"s":[0.890196084976,0.600000023842,0.694117665291,1],"e":[0.329411774874,0.596078455448,0.800000011921,1]},{"i":{"x":[0.833],"y":[0.833]},"o":{"x":[0.167],"y":[0.167]},"n":["0p833_0p833_0p167_0p167"],"t":56,"s":[0.329411774874,0.596078455448,0.800000011921,1],"e":[0.549019634724,0.274509817362,0.709803938866,1]},{"t":66}],"ix":3},"o":{"a":0,"k":100,"ix":4},"w":{"a":1,"k":[{"i":{"x":[0.833],"y":[0.833]},"o":{"x":[0.167],"y":[0.167]},"n":["0p833_0p833_0p167_0p167"],"t":56,"s":[5],"e":[0]},{"t":89}],"ix":5},"lc":2,"lj":1,"ml":4,"nm":"Stroke 1","mn":"ADBE Vector Graphic - Stroke","hd":false},{"ty":"tr","p":{"a":0,"k":[0,0],"ix":2},"a":{"a":0,"k":[0,0],"ix":1},"s":{"a":0,"k":[100,100],"ix":3},"r":{"a":0,"k":0,"ix":6},"o":{"a":0,"k":100,"ix":7},"sk":{"a":0,"k":0,"ix":4},"sa":{"a":0,"k":0,"ix":5},"nm":"Transform"}],"nm":"Shape 1","np":3,"cix":2,"ix":1,"mn":"ADBE Vector Group","hd":false}],"ip":44,"op":90,"st":-44,"bm":0},{"ddd":0,"ind":9,"ty":4,"nm":"Dot6","sr":1,"ks":{"o":{"a":0,"k":100,"ix":11},"r":{"a":0,"k":-117.1,"ix":10},"p":{"a":0,"k":[25,25,0],"ix":2},"a":{"a":0,"k":[0,0,0],"ix":1},"s":{"a":0,"k":[40,40,100],"ix":6}},"ao":0,"shapes":[{"ty":"gr","it":[{"ind":0,"ty":"sh","ix":1,"ks":{"a":0,"k":{"i":[[0,0],[0,0]],"o":[[0,0],[0,0]],"v":[[-37.5,-40.5],[-1,0.5]],"c":false},"ix":2},"nm":"Path 1","mn":"ADBE Vector Shape - Group","hd":false},{"ty":"tm","s":{"a":1,"k":[{"i":{"x":[0.833],"y":[0.833]},"o":{"x":[0.167],"y":[0.167]},"n":["0p833_0p833_0p167_0p167"],"t":44,"s":[47],"e":[29]},{"i":{"x":[0.833],"y":[0.833]},"o":{"x":[0.167],"y":[0.167]},"n":["0p833_0p833_0p167_0p167"],"t":56,"s":[29],"e":[9]},{"t":78}],"ix":1},"e":{"a":1,"k":[{"i":{"x":[0.833],"y":[0.833]},"o":{"x":[0.167],"y":[0.167]},"n":["0p833_0p833_0p167_0p167"],"t":44,"s":[48],"e":[30]},{"i":{"x":[0.833],"y":[0.833]},"o":{"x":[0.167],"y":[0.167]},"n":["0p833_0p833_0p167_0p167"],"t":56,"s":[30],"e":[10]},{"t":78}],"ix":2},"o":{"a":0,"k":0,"ix":3},"m":1,"ix":2,"nm":"Trim Paths 1","mn":"ADBE Vector Filter - Trim","hd":false},{"ty":"st","c":{"a":1,"k":[{"i":{"x":[0.833],"y":[0.833]},"o":{"x":[0.167],"y":[0.167]},"n":["0p833_0p833_0p167_0p167"],"t":44,"s":[0.61960786581,0.815686285496,0.956862747669,1],"e":[0.701960802078,0.843137264252,0.658823549747,1]},{"t":56}],"ix":3},"o":{"a":0,"k":100,"ix":4},"w":{"a":1,"k":[{"i":{"x":[0.833],"y":[0.833]},"o":{"x":[0.167],"y":[0.167]},"n":["0p833_0p833_0p167_0p167"],"t":44,"s":[5],"e":[2]},{"i":{"x":[0.833],"y":[0.833]},"o":{"x":[0.167],"y":[0.167]},"n":["0p833_0p833_0p167_0p167"],"t":56,"s":[2],"e":[0]},{"t":70}],"ix":5},"lc":2,"lj":1,"ml":4,"nm":"Stroke 1","mn":"ADBE Vector Graphic - Stroke","hd":false},{"ty":"tm","s":{"a":0,"k":29,"ix":1},"e":{"a":0,"k":30,"ix":2},"o":{"a":0,"k":0,"ix":3},"m":1,"ix":4,"nm":"Trim Paths 2","mn":"ADBE Vector Filter - Trim","hd":false},{"ty":"tr","p":{"a":0,"k":[0,0],"ix":2},"a":{"a":0,"k":[0,0],"ix":1},"s":{"a":0,"k":[100,100],"ix":3},"r":{"a":0,"k":0,"ix":6},"o":{"a":0,"k":100,"ix":7},"sk":{"a":0,"k":0,"ix":4},"sa":{"a":0,"k":0,"ix":5},"nm":"Transform"}],"nm":"Shape 1","np":4,"cix":2,"ix":1,"mn":"ADBE Vector Group","hd":false}],"ip":44,"op":90,"st":-44,"bm":0},{"ddd":0,"ind":10,"ty":4,"nm":"Dot5","sr":1,"ks":{"o":{"a":0,"k":100,"ix":11},"r":{"a":0,"k":-103.7,"ix":10},"p":{"a":0,"k":[25,25,0],"ix":2},"a":{"a":0,"k":[0,0,0],"ix":1},"s":{"a":0,"k":[40,40,100],"ix":6}},"ao":0,"shapes":[{"ty":"gr","it":[{"ind":0,"ty":"sh","ix":1,"ks":{"a":0,"k":{"i":[[0,0],[0,0]],"o":[[0,0],[0,0]],"v":[[-37.5,-40.5],[-1,0.5]],"c":false},"ix":2},"nm":"Path 1","mn":"ADBE Vector Shape - Group","hd":false},{"ty":"tm","s":{"a":1,"k":[{"i":{"x":[0.833],"y":[0.833]},"o":{"x":[0.167],"y":[0.167]},"n":["0p833_0p833_0p167_0p167"],"t":44,"s":[44],"e":[19]},{"i":{"x":[0.833],"y":[0.833]},"o":{"x":[0.167],"y":[0.167]},"n":["0p833_0p833_0p167_0p167"],"t":56,"s":[19],"e":[0]},{"t":89}],"ix":1},"e":{"a":1,"k":[{"i":{"x":[0.833],"y":[0.833]},"o":{"x":[0.167],"y":[0.167]},"n":["0p833_0p833_0p167_0p167"],"t":44,"s":[45],"e":[20]},{"i":{"x":[0.833],"y":[0.833]},"o":{"x":[0.167],"y":[0.167]},"n":["0p833_0p833_0p167_0p167"],"t":56,"s":[20],"e":[1]},{"t":89}],"ix":2},"o":{"a":0,"k":0,"ix":3},"m":1,"ix":2,"nm":"Trim Paths 1","mn":"ADBE Vector Filter - Trim","hd":false},{"ty":"st","c":{"a":1,"k":[{"i":{"x":[0.833],"y":[0.833]},"o":{"x":[0.167],"y":[0.167]},"n":["0p833_0p833_0p167_0p167"],"t":44,"s":[0.721568644047,0.847058832645,0.949019610882,1],"e":[0.701960802078,0.843137264252,0.670588254929,1]},{"i":{"x":[0.833],"y":[0.833]},"o":{"x":[0.167],"y":[0.167]},"n":["0p833_0p833_0p167_0p167"],"t":56,"s":[0.701960802078,0.843137264252,0.670588254929,1],"e":[0.549019634724,0.274509817362,0.709803938866,1]},{"t":66}],"ix":3},"o":{"a":0,"k":100,"ix":4},"w":{"a":1,"k":[{"i":{"x":[0.833],"y":[0.833]},"o":{"x":[0.167],"y":[0.167]},"n":["0p833_0p833_0p167_0p167"],"t":56,"s":[5],"e":[0]},{"t":89}],"ix":5},"lc":2,"lj":1,"ml":4,"nm":"Stroke 1","mn":"ADBE Vector Graphic - Stroke","hd":false},{"ty":"tr","p":{"a":0,"k":[0,0],"ix":2},"a":{"a":0,"k":[0,0],"ix":1},"s":{"a":0,"k":[100,100],"ix":3},"r":{"a":0,"k":0,"ix":6},"o":{"a":0,"k":100,"ix":7},"sk":{"a":0,"k":0,"ix":4},"sa":{"a":0,"k":0,"ix":5},"nm":"Transform"}],"nm":"Shape 1","np":3,"cix":2,"ix":1,"mn":"ADBE Vector Group","hd":false}],"ip":44,"op":90,"st":-44,"bm":0},{"ddd":0,"ind":11,"ty":4,"nm":"Dot4","sr":1,"ks":{"o":{"a":0,"k":100,"ix":11},"r":{"a":0,"k":-69.3,"ix":10},"p":{"a":0,"k":[25,25,0],"ix":2},"a":{"a":0,"k":[0,0,0],"ix":1},"s":{"a":0,"k":[40,40,100],"ix":6}},"ao":0,"shapes":[{"ty":"gr","it":[{"ind":0,"ty":"sh","ix":1,"ks":{"a":0,"k":{"i":[[0,0],[0,0]],"o":[[0,0],[0,0]],"v":[[-37.5,-40.5],[-1,0.5]],"c":false},"ix":2},"nm":"Path 1","mn":"ADBE Vector Shape - Group","hd":false},{"ty":"tm","s":{"a":1,"k":[{"i":{"x":[0.833],"y":[0.833]},"o":{"x":[0.167],"y":[0.167]},"n":["0p833_0p833_0p167_0p167"],"t":44,"s":[47],"e":[29]},{"i":{"x":[0.833],"y":[0.833]},"o":{"x":[0.167],"y":[0.167]},"n":["0p833_0p833_0p167_0p167"],"t":56,"s":[29],"e":[9]},{"t":78}],"ix":1},"e":{"a":1,"k":[{"i":{"x":[0.833],"y":[0.833]},"o":{"x":[0.167],"y":[0.167]},"n":["0p833_0p833_0p167_0p167"],"t":44,"s":[48],"e":[30]},{"i":{"x":[0.833],"y":[0.833]},"o":{"x":[0.167],"y":[0.167]},"n":["0p833_0p833_0p167_0p167"],"t":56,"s":[30],"e":[10]},{"t":78}],"ix":2},"o":{"a":0,"k":0,"ix":3},"m":1,"ix":2,"nm":"Trim Paths 1","mn":"ADBE Vector Filter - Trim","hd":false},{"ty":"st","c":{"a":1,"k":[{"i":{"x":[0.833],"y":[0.833]},"o":{"x":[0.167],"y":[0.167]},"n":["0p833_0p833_0p167_0p167"],"t":44,"s":[0.800000011921,0.580392181873,0.929411768913,1],"e":[0.701960802078,0.847058832645,0.658823549747,1]},{"t":56}],"ix":3},"o":{"a":0,"k":100,"ix":4},"w":{"a":1,"k":[{"i":{"x":[0.833],"y":[0.833]},"o":{"x":[0.167],"y":[0.167]},"n":["0p833_0p833_0p167_0p167"],"t":44,"s":[5],"e":[2]},{"i":{"x":[0.833],"y":[0.833]},"o":{"x":[0.167],"y":[0.167]},"n":["0p833_0p833_0p167_0p167"],"t":56,"s":[2],"e":[0]},{"t":70}],"ix":5},"lc":2,"lj":1,"ml":4,"nm":"Stroke 1","mn":"ADBE Vector Graphic - Stroke","hd":false},{"ty":"tr","p":{"a":0,"k":[0,0],"ix":2},"a":{"a":0,"k":[0,0],"ix":1},"s":{"a":0,"k":[100,100],"ix":3},"r":{"a":0,"k":0,"ix":6},"o":{"a":0,"k":100,"ix":7},"sk":{"a":0,"k":0,"ix":4},"sa":{"a":0,"k":0,"ix":5},"nm":"Transform"}],"nm":"Shape 1","np":3,"cix":2,"ix":1,"mn":"ADBE Vector Group","hd":false}],"ip":44,"op":90,"st":-44,"bm":0},{"ddd":0,"ind":12,"ty":4,"nm":"Dot3","sr":1,"ks":{"o":{"a":0,"k":100,"ix":11},"r":{"a":0,"k":-55.9,"ix":10},"p":{"a":0,"k":[25,25,0],"ix":2},"a":{"a":0,"k":[0,0,0],"ix":1},"s":{"a":0,"k":[40,40,100],"ix":6}},"ao":0,"shapes":[{"ty":"gr","it":[{"ind":0,"ty":"sh","ix":1,"ks":{"a":0,"k":{"i":[[0,0],[0,0]],"o":[[0,0],[0,0]],"v":[[-37.5,-40.5],[-1,0.5]],"c":false},"ix":2},"nm":"Path 1","mn":"ADBE Vector Shape - Group","hd":false},{"ty":"tm","s":{"a":1,"k":[{"i":{"x":[0.833],"y":[0.833]},"o":{"x":[0.167],"y":[0.167]},"n":["0p833_0p833_0p167_0p167"],"t":44,"s":[44],"e":[19]},{"i":{"x":[0.833],"y":[0.833]},"o":{"x":[0.167],"y":[0.167]},"n":["0p833_0p833_0p167_0p167"],"t":56,"s":[19],"e":[0]},{"t":89}],"ix":1},"e":{"a":1,"k":[{"i":{"x":[0.833],"y":[0.833]},"o":{"x":[0.167],"y":[0.167]},"n":["0p833_0p833_0p167_0p167"],"t":44,"s":[45],"e":[20]},{"i":{"x":[0.833],"y":[0.833]},"o":{"x":[0.167],"y":[0.167]},"n":["0p833_0p833_0p167_0p167"],"t":56,"s":[20],"e":[1]},{"t":89}],"ix":2},"o":{"a":0,"k":0,"ix":3},"m":1,"ix":2,"nm":"Trim Paths 1","mn":"ADBE Vector Filter - Trim","hd":false},{"ty":"st","c":{"a":1,"k":[{"i":{"x":[0.833],"y":[0.833]},"o":{"x":[0.167],"y":[0.167]},"n":["0p833_0p833_0p167_0p167"],"t":44,"s":[0.643137276173,0.811764717102,0.972549021244,1],"e":[0.701960802078,0.847058832645,0.658823549747,1]},{"i":{"x":[0.833],"y":[0.833]},"o":{"x":[0.167],"y":[0.167]},"n":["0p833_0p833_0p167_0p167"],"t":56,"s":[0.701960802078,0.847058832645,0.658823549747,1],"e":[0.549019634724,0.274509817362,0.709803938866,1]},{"t":66}],"ix":3},"o":{"a":0,"k":100,"ix":4},"w":{"a":1,"k":[{"i":{"x":[0.833],"y":[0.833]},"o":{"x":[0.167],"y":[0.167]},"n":["0p833_0p833_0p167_0p167"],"t":56,"s":[5],"e":[0]},{"t":89}],"ix":5},"lc":2,"lj":1,"ml":4,"nm":"Stroke 1","mn":"ADBE Vector Graphic - Stroke","hd":false},{"ty":"tr","p":{"a":0,"k":[0,0],"ix":2},"a":{"a":0,"k":[0,0],"ix":1},"s":{"a":0,"k":[100,100],"ix":3},"r":{"a":0,"k":0,"ix":6},"o":{"a":0,"k":100,"ix":7},"sk":{"a":0,"k":0,"ix":4},"sa":{"a":0,"k":0,"ix":5},"nm":"Transform"}],"nm":"Shape 1","np":3,"cix":2,"ix":1,"mn":"ADBE Vector Group","hd":false}],"ip":44,"op":90,"st":-44,"bm":0},{"ddd":0,"ind":13,"ty":4,"nm":"Dot2","sr":1,"ks":{"o":{"a":0,"k":100,"ix":11},"r":{"a":0,"k":-13.4,"ix":10},"p":{"a":0,"k":[25,25,0],"ix":2},"a":{"a":0,"k":[0,0,0],"ix":1},"s":{"a":0,"k":[40,40,100],"ix":6}},"ao":0,"shapes":[{"ty":"gr","it":[{"ind":0,"ty":"sh","ix":1,"ks":{"a":0,"k":{"i":[[0,0],[0,0]],"o":[[0,0],[0,0]],"v":[[-37.5,-40.5],[-1,0.5]],"c":false},"ix":2},"nm":"Path 1","mn":"ADBE Vector Shape - Group","hd":false},{"ty":"tm","s":{"a":1,"k":[{"i":{"x":[0.833],"y":[0.833]},"o":{"x":[0.167],"y":[0.167]},"n":["0p833_0p833_0p167_0p167"],"t":44,"s":[47],"e":[29]},{"i":{"x":[0.833],"y":[0.833]},"o":{"x":[0.167],"y":[0.167]},"n":["0p833_0p833_0p167_0p167"],"t":56,"s":[29],"e":[9]},{"t":78}],"ix":1},"e":{"a":1,"k":[{"i":{"x":[0.833],"y":[0.833]},"o":{"x":[0.167],"y":[0.167]},"n":["0p833_0p833_0p167_0p167"],"t":44,"s":[48],"e":[30]},{"i":{"x":[0.833],"y":[0.833]},"o":{"x":[0.167],"y":[0.167]},"n":["0p833_0p833_0p167_0p167"],"t":56,"s":[30],"e":[10]},{"t":78}],"ix":2},"o":{"a":0,"k":0,"ix":3},"m":1,"ix":2,"nm":"Trim Paths 1","mn":"ADBE Vector Filter - Trim","hd":false},{"ty":"st","c":{"a":1,"k":[{"i":{"x":[0.833],"y":[0.833]},"o":{"x":[0.167],"y":[0.167]},"n":["0p833_0p833_0p167_0p167"],"t":44,"s":[0.607843160629,0.886274516582,0.78823530674,1],"e":[0.631372570992,0.509803950787,0.623529434204,1]},{"t":56}],"ix":3},"o":{"a":0,"k":100,"ix":4},"w":{"a":1,"k":[{"i":{"x":[0.833],"y":[0.833]},"o":{"x":[0.167],"y":[0.167]},"n":["0p833_0p833_0p167_0p167"],"t":44,"s":[5],"e":[2]},{"i":{"x":[0.833],"y":[0.833]},"o":{"x":[0.167],"y":[0.167]},"n":["0p833_0p833_0p167_0p167"],"t":56,"s":[2],"e":[0]},{"t":70}],"ix":5},"lc":2,"lj":1,"ml":4,"nm":"Stroke 1","mn":"ADBE Vector Graphic - Stroke","hd":false},{"ty":"tr","p":{"a":0,"k":[0,0],"ix":2},"a":{"a":0,"k":[0,0],"ix":1},"s":{"a":0,"k":[100,100],"ix":3},"r":{"a":0,"k":0,"ix":6},"o":{"a":0,"k":100,"ix":7},"sk":{"a":0,"k":0,"ix":4},"sa":{"a":0,"k":0,"ix":5},"nm":"Transform"}],"nm":"Shape 1","np":3,"cix":2,"ix":1,"mn":"ADBE Vector Group","hd":false}],"ip":44,"op":90,"st":-44,"bm":0},{"ddd":0,"ind":14,"ty":4,"nm":"Dot1","sr":1,"ks":{"o":{"a":0,"k":100,"ix":11},"r":{"a":0,"k":0,"ix":10},"p":{"a":0,"k":[25,25,0],"ix":2},"a":{"a":0,"k":[0,0,0],"ix":1},"s":{"a":0,"k":[40,40,100],"ix":6}},"ao":0,"shapes":[{"ty":"gr","it":[{"ind":0,"ty":"sh","ix":1,"ks":{"a":0,"k":{"i":[[0,0],[0,0]],"o":[[0,0],[0,0]],"v":[[-37.5,-40.5],[-1,0.5]],"c":false},"ix":2},"nm":"Path 1","mn":"ADBE Vector Shape - Group","hd":false},{"ty":"tm","s":{"a":1,"k":[{"i":{"x":[0.833],"y":[0.833]},"o":{"x":[0.167],"y":[0.167]},"n":["0p833_0p833_0p167_0p167"],"t":44,"s":[44],"e":[19]},{"i":{"x":[0.833],"y":[0.833]},"o":{"x":[0.167],"y":[0.167]},"n":["0p833_0p833_0p167_0p167"],"t":56,"s":[19],"e":[0]},{"t":89}],"ix":1},"e":{"a":1,"k":[{"i":{"x":[0.833],"y":[0.833]},"o":{"x":[0.167],"y":[0.167]},"n":["0p833_0p833_0p167_0p167"],"t":44,"s":[45],"e":[20]},{"i":{"x":[0.833],"y":[0.833]},"o":{"x":[0.167],"y":[0.167]},"n":["0p833_0p833_0p167_0p167"],"t":56,"s":[20],"e":[1]},{"t":89}],"ix":2},"o":{"a":0,"k":0,"ix":3},"m":1,"ix":2,"nm":"Trim Paths 1","mn":"ADBE Vector Filter - Trim","hd":false},{"ty":"st","c":{"a":1,"k":[{"i":{"x":[0.833],"y":[0.833]},"o":{"x":[0.167],"y":[0.167]},"n":["0p833_0p833_0p167_0p167"],"t":44,"s":[0.61960786581,0.882352948189,0.780392169952,1],"e":[0.800000011921,0.521568655968,0.760784327984,1]},{"i":{"x":[0.833],"y":[0.833]},"o":{"x":[0.167],"y":[0.167]},"n":["0p833_0p833_0p167_0p167"],"t":56,"s":[0.800000011921,0.521568655968,0.760784327984,1],"e":[0.549019634724,0.274509817362,0.709803938866,1]},{"t":66}],"ix":3},"o":{"a":0,"k":100,"ix":4},"w":{"a":1,"k":[{"i":{"x":[0.833],"y":[0.833]},"o":{"x":[0.167],"y":[0.167]},"n":["0p833_0p833_0p167_0p167"],"t":56,"s":[5],"e":[0]},{"t":89}],"ix":5},"lc":2,"lj":1,"ml":4,"nm":"Stroke 1","mn":"ADBE Vector Graphic - Stroke","hd":false},{"ty":"tr","p":{"a":0,"k":[0,0],"ix":2},"a":{"a":0,"k":[0,0],"ix":1},"s":{"a":0,"k":[100,100],"ix":3},"r":{"a":0,"k":0,"ix":6},
```

Answer (score 0):

I tried this following your link above. The animation starts playing straight away for me.

When refreshing the page, also plays straightaway.

When I say straight away, I mean after the resources are downloaded. Even on page refresh, there's 540kb of data that downloaded again, after about 4Mb has been cached.

I have a very fast Internet connection though. If I try this via my phone's connection, it takes 6 or 7 seconds to download and start playing.

Is it possible that the delay you are experiencing is the time it's taking to download that 4Mb on a slower connection?

Of that 540kb, 416Kb is vendor.????.js. Perhaps allowing that to be cached might help?

Comment: It's compiled on my phone in the resources directory, I don't download the json.

Answer (score 0):

The start of the animation is a white heart, which doesn't show up on the background. Around frame 25 onwards you see the main part of the animation.

[image: white heart on transparent background]

I'm not sure if you can easily remove this from the JSON, though as a work around you're able to play a segment of an animation as follows:

```js
window.onload = function() {
  const player = document.querySelector("lottie-player");
  player.load("https://assets5.lottiefiles.com/packages/lf20_hmpf0dsc.json");
  var lw = player.getLottie();
  lw.loop = true;
  lw.playSegments([30, 116], false);
}
```

```html
<script src="https://unpkg.com/@lottiefiles/lottie-player@latest/dist/lottie-player.js" type="module"></script>
<lottie-player loop controls mode="normal" style="width: 400px">
</lottie-player>
```

#### Update with a simpler method:

In your lottie JSON, set IP to 30 and this should start the animation at frame 30 where it's visible.